# InDesign - Show/Hide multiple forms on different pages with one button

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm trying to create a multiple language interactive document in Id. So far I can create flags (language buttons) that can toggle on/off languages (different frames) on one page, but is there a way to do this throughout the document with one click?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are up to. If you want to work with different languages within the indesign document, you can either choose to work with one layer per language or use conditional text.
However if you want to have such a language switch in outputed document such as a PDF or an ePub, then it's tougher because you can't change InDesign layer visibility in such formats. Maybe a script in the Acrobat side may manage it to the condition you actually create a PDF that embeds layers.
You could use also state objects but that wouldn't apply to PDFs.

Comment: This is just the tip of the iceberg, because I need to extract the HTML5 from the ePub file, but like you wrote it will be hard to change layer visibility without a script.

What I'm trying to do is create a presentation in HTML5 to import in Adobe Captivate, because Captivate is a very bad designing tool. All in all I'm trying to develop a workflow from a program like InDesign or other, import it in Captivate to maintain SCORM compatibilities and place it in Moodle.